# All abstract, default, and static methods in an interface are implicitly public, so you can omit the public modifier

Tags: java

Hi i am beginner in learning java.While studying about interfaces i came across through this line "All abstract, default, and static methods in an interface are implicitly public, so you can omit the public modifier."In my understanding "default" is already a access modifier,then why default method will be again "public".Please clarify this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`default` is not an access modifier. `default` indicates a default implementation of an interface method. It was introduced in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

The JLS makes this clear:

It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the public and/or abstract modifier for a method declared in an interface.